# EPiserver: Get list of available languages for current page

Tags: c#, episerver

I am trying to get the list of available languages for the current page in EPiserver. I currently have the following:

```
public static IHtmlString HrefLangLinks(this PageData currentPage)
        {
            IContentRepository repo = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentRepository>();
            var pageLanguagesBranches = repo.GetLanguageBranches<PageData>(currentPage.ContentLink).ToList();
            var availablePageLanguages = FilterForVisitor.Filter(pageLanguagesBranches).OfType<PageData>();

            // Dictionary<String, String>
            return null;
        }
```

At the moment however `availablePageLanguages` contains: {System.Linq.Enumerable.d__95}

How can I get a list of the names of the languages? For example de-DE, en-DE or de-AT ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the available languages of a specific page, you can read the `PageData.ExistingLanguages` property from your current page. That will give you an `IEnumerable<CultureInfo>` result. And to get the language code from each `CultureInfo` object, read the `CultureInfo.Name` property.

The code would look like this:

```
currentPage.ExistingLanguages.Select(culture => culture.Name);
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan. As a test I tried the following: var Test = currentPage.ExistingLanguages.Select(culture => culture.Name); the content of the variable is: System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Globalization.CultureInfo,System.String]. I guess I missed something ?

Comment: That's because the return-type is an `Enumerable`, which is a way of lazy-loading in .Net. If you add `.ToArray()` to the end, you will get an array of strings.

Comment: Ah I get now. Thanks, will try it later today!